# what -s (small letter s) command line swich in gcc mean?

Tags: gcc, mingw

I have this line:

```
g++ -I d:\boost -Os -s -o test.exe test.cpp -lshlwapi -lgdi32 -std=c++11 -ftree-vectorize -static`
```

and I cannot find what the `-s` is for , I know what the big S does but there is nothing about the small one.

And btw, where is the actual command line gcc reference, this: http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html is 10 years old.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ -- The two options that you mention are under "Options That Control Optimization" and "Options for Linking".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man gcc`:

> -s  Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the
>   executable

It's an equivalent to `strip` command.